# CSS different sizes for fonts (only watchable on mobile device)

Tags: css, html, font-size, difference

I have set up a mobile website for http://bit.ly/1Hwbn94 ... but I am having some obstacles, unfortunately, which I need your help with. I just can not see the issues anymore.

Problem: On http://bit.ly/1DXm9m4 it shows me different sizes for p and li, although they are set to 1rem both. The same happens on http://bit.ly/1EmktnD (here everything seems to be small) or other pages.

CSS code

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 800px) {
body {background: none;}
#logo {margin-left: 0px;}
#header {width: 100%; padding: 1.875rem;}
#container {width: 100%; padding: 1.875rem;}
.box {width: 100%; margin: 0;}
#leftcol {display: none;}
#rightcol {width: auto; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .93);}
img {max-width: 100% !important; height: auto;}
p {font-size: 1rem; margin-bottom: 1rem;}
h1 {font-size: 2.5rem; font-weight: bold;}
h2 {font-size: 2rem; font-weight: bold;}
.kasten {width: 100%;}
.person1 {font-size: 1rem; width: 40%; float: left; margin-right: 10rem;}
.person2 {margin-bottom:1.5rem;}
li {font-size: 1rem;}
}
```

Comment: You missed an </ul> but that seems not the reason, I think maybe you can check your html structure first

Comment: I noticed that too, the media query seems to not be kicking in from that point on the first problem page.

Comment: Yeah, I added the missing /ul, but that was not the problem, because on other pages I did not miss it. :\

Comment: Have you set a viewport meta tag to control scaling on mobile? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: Jeff, do you want to add that as an answer, so I can rate and clean this question? Thanks, mate. I think, I worked it out for now. :) There is just a small issue left: When I visit the website with a mobile device, it is always a bit zoomed in, leaving out some mm on the right side. Someone knows why?